# how to overlap the keyboard on bottom view and show only specific views on top of keyboard when keyboard is opened in android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a requirement to show an editText on top of keyboard when the keyboard opens. But at the same time I have to hide the bottom tab navigation view on my fragment screen. It should be behind the keyboard.

I have tried multiple combinations for android:windowSoftInputMode but in some cases, either the EditTexts is not displayed or the entire screen is showing on top of keyboard.

Is there a way to keep the screen view as it is and open the keyboard with EditText on top of it.

Comment: I have fixed it by explicitly setting the windowSoftInputMode to adjustResize in my fragment like 
requireActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

and then applying the ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener for measuring the keyboard height and hiding the bottom view